# Why "int/boolean/..." are primary types which have no "behavior" where type is "behavior specification"

Tags: java, types

From this paper: http://www-public.int-evry.fr/~gibson/Teaching/CSC7322/ReadingMaterial/Wegner87.pdf

It defines `type`:

> type: A type is a behavior specification that may be used to generate instances having the behavior.

But I found in this document: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/riccardo/courses/csu370-fa07/lect4.pdf

It says Java has:

1. primitive types: types corresponding to primitive values, including int, short, long,
   byte, char, float, double, and boolean.
2. null type: the type of the value null

But the "primitive types" are values which don't have behavior, and `null` is also value.

Why are they "type"s? Do they reference the same concept "type"?

---

About "behavior", in my current understand, it's what a variable or entity provides us to invoke (seems I'm talking about object). But since type is not only for "object" related languages, so I'm really not sure what "behavior" is now.

Maybe the real question should be: What does "behavior" mean in the definition of "type"?

Comment: Then what has behaviour, according to you?

Comment: `"Do they reference the same concept "type"?"` Whithout fully reading those papers I'd say no. The first one refers to the concept of a type in the OOP paradigm. The second one discusses more of a technical term: The type of a variable in Java.

Comment: Behavior? I'd say how arithmetic works with primitives _is_ behavior, `null` causing `NullPointerExceptions` is behavior etc.

Comment: @Rhymoid, updated the question to add the "behavior" understanding.

Comment: `int i = 1 + 1` and `x` is now `2`. Now let's try `boolean b = true || false`. OK, `b` would be `true` now. But what if we do `1 + true`. The answer is nothing. Clearly primitives do have behaviour as we can do the first two examples based on that behaviour, but the third one fails, because it does not conform to the behaviour expected.

Answer (score 3):

Primitive types and Null types are "types" because the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) specifies them as such. The JLS does not provide a formal definition of "type" other than that there are three types a `ReferenceType`, a `PrimitiveType`, and null type [[JLS 4.1]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1).

It is likely the second paper linked is reusing the terms defined in the JLS.